# Verifying Hashed password

Tags: c#, hash, salt

Good day Guys,

I have an issue. I have been able to create User accounts with user_ID, Username and Password fields.

The password is Hashed and salted and its working fine.
Now i want to create a login form where user needs to be authenticated with username and password.

I want to verify if the password supplied and username is correct. this password has to be hash first and then compare with what is in the database.

Below is my code, but it keeps bringing error of incorrect password.

```
try
        {

            string connString = CommonVariables.ConnectionString;
            // Hashing the password field first for it to be 



            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Users WHERE (Username = @Username) ";
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                {
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Password.Text.Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Username.Text.Trim();





                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //  string vsibility = reader["Visibility"].ToString(); //Getting the  value of the visibility to determine if the user can logon or not
                            // string user_role = reader["User_Role"].ToString(); // Getting the User_role of the person login on
                            string mypassword = reader["password"].ToString();
                            var hash = PasswordHashing.SecurePasswordHasher.Hash(mypassword);
                            var hashverify = PasswordHashing.SecurePasswordHasher.Verify(txt_Password.Text.Trim(), hash);

                            if (hashverify == true)
                            {
                                this.Hide();
                                new Mainmenu().Show(); ;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("incorrect password" + mypassword);
                            }
                        }





                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username, Please Confirm", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        txt_Username.Focus();
                        return;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(c.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the salt being stored? Isn't that missing here, or is it part of your password hasher?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that it is the hashed password which is stored in the database. If so, your `hash` variable should be just `var hash = mypassword` without an extra hash call (computing the hash of a hash).

Comment: @KurtHamilton, The salt is part of the hasher. I will add the hashing algorithm to edit

Comment: @erdomke I just saw that too. There's a double hashing afoot

Comment: @erdomke, wow, thanks. I was still hashing it again. My bad. Can you put this as answer so that i can tick it? It worked well

Comment: @mantics No problem. Glad the extra pair of eyes helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are storing the hash of the password in the database, it appears that you are double hashing it. In particular, the line

```
var hash = PasswordHashing.SecurePasswordHasher.Hash(mypassword);
```

appears to be computing the hash of an already hashed password. Changing this to `var hash = mypassword;` could help with comparing the passwords.